# Can a static method be called from either a static, or non-static, context? In java

Tags: java

I'm just curious to know whether in Java can a static method be called from either a static, or non-static, context?

Comment: Did you try it ?

Comment: You can certainly invoke a static method from inside an instance method. And there is a "convenience feature" of javac that allows you to do `myInstance.staticMethod()` and get the same result as if you said `MyClass.staticMethod()` where `MyClass` is the declared class for the `myInstance` variable.

Comment: @HotLicks: Please make this an answer.

Comment: Somebody voted to close as "not constructive". I'm not sure this is the right reason.

Comment: @0A0D Probably he has no interest or time in answering this simple question.  :-)

Comment: @HotLicks - That feature is usually better avoided, since it implies dynamic binding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it totally can be called from either a static, or non-static, context.

Comment: ;D I like this answer

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely: since static methods do not need an instance reference, they can be called from both contexts. Only instance methods have a restriction on being called on an object, because they implicitly take the object as an additional argument.

Answer (score 2):

The JVM will tell you faster than we will, but you can call static methods from either static or non-static contexts.

You cannot call a non-static method from a static context without a reference to an object instance.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we could call it.

```
public class A{

  public static void static_B(){}
  public void normal_C(){
    A.static_B();
    static_B();
  }
  public void static_C(){
    A.static_B();
    static_B();
  }

}
```

The above code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is pretty much possible. But since static members exist at class level, it is always a good practice to use a static member by class name instead of referring it by object reference.